# Как добавить элемент при первом клике, а при втором его удалить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно, чтобы при первом нажатии на кнопку элемент добавлялся на страницу, а при последующем удалялся с неё. Скрипт ниже работает почему-то только 1 раз, то есть при первом и втором клике. При третьем элемент просто перестает появляется. Сразу скажу, что метод скрытия элемента css свойством display: none/block мне подходит, нужно именно добавлять и удалять элемент при клике на кнопку.

```
<button class="menu_btn"></button>
      <div class="menu-content"></div>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var menuBtn = $('.menu_btn');
        menuBtn.on('click',function(event) {
       menuBtn.toggleClass('menu_btn_active');

    });
     });
    </script>

    <script> $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu_btn").click(function(){ 
          $(".menu-content").append(
          "<div class='effects'>Эффект</div>"); 
        $(".effects").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".menu_btn_active").click(function(){  
          $(".effects").fadeOut(400);
          setTimeout(function() { 
            $(".effects").remove(); 
          }, 100);
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menuBtn = $('.menu_btn');

  menuBtn.click(function(event) { 
    // это активная кнопка?
    if (event.target.classList.contains('menu_btn_active')) {
      $(".effects").fadeOut(400);
      setTimeout(function () { 
        $(".effects").remove(); 
      }, 300);
    } else {
      // обратите внимание на display: none;
      $(".menu-content").append("<div class='effects' style='display: none;'>Эффект</div>"); 
      $(".effects").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    // переключаем вконце
    menuBtn.toggleClass('menu_btn_active');
    return false;
  });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu_btn">Button</button>
      <div class="menu-content"></div>
```

Comment: ппц, ну и код))) это все делается ТРЕМЯ строками....

Comment: я не джикюерщик, так что не про в нем, пользуюсь фреймворками))) Будет интересно посмотреть на решение из трех строк.

Answer (score 2):

Ну или если конкретно добавить/удалить, то вот таким образом можно.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 if($(this).attr('connect')){
   $('.text').remove();
  }
 else{
   $(this).parents('div').append('<p class=text>TExt</p>');
    $(this).attr('connect', 'true');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем все усложнять ? Всего 3 строки кода.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 $('.text').fadeToggle('slow'); 
  //or
  //$(this).next().fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.text{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">button</button>
<p class="text">TExt</p>
```

Comment: Я же написал - такой метод мне подходит)